# Injectable in DynamicComponentLoader error - Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm dynamically loading components into my menu bar using `DynamicComponentLoader`.

This is what my component class looks like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'create-submenu-component',
  templateUrl: 'common/create/create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['common/create/create.component.css'],
  directives: [CreateAssetComponent]
})
export class CreateSubmenuComponent {
  public model: Model;

  constructor(private _modelService:ModelService, public http: Http) {
    this.model = this._modelService.getModel();
  }
}
```

And the dynamic component creation method:

```
constructor(public injector:Injector){}

loadCreateSubMenu(){
  this.dcl.loadAsRoot(CreateSubmenuComponent, '#Create', this.injector);
}
```

When I'm trying to load the component that contains the Service I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot resolve all parameters for 'CreateSubmenuComponent'(undefined, Http). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'CreateSubmenuComponent' is decorated with Injectable.`

The Service being injected is showing up as undefined. Submenu Components that do not rely on a Service load fine. How do I inject the service into the dynamically created component?

Comment: Where does `this.injector` come from?

Comment: Edited to reflect where this.injector is coming from. My use of DynamicComponentLoader was pulled from the example on the Angular2 site: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html

Comment: Have you tried not passing the injector?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error. I'm wondering if using LoadNextToLocation instead of LoadAsRoot would work with ModelService placed in the providers location? I think I need to dig into the code base to understand what DynamicComponentLoader is actually doing.

Comment: `loadAsRoot` is built only for bootstrapping root. For DCL you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 (beta.16 version). For making `loadAsRoot` work see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6370#issuecomment-193896657

Comment: Great information, thank you!